# Exception Handling works only once in running program

Tags: java, exception, formatexception

Initially I tried to put the `try` statement into the `while` loop, however, I was encountered with several errors. The program runs perfectly except when I input a irregular character once it gives me the Printed line I inputted I created, however, when I inputted another one again, the line does not pop up and rather gives me a format exception error.

**AddNumbersrealone2.java**

```
import java.io.*;

// create the class
public class AddNumbersrealone2
{
    // allows i/o
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {   // initalize variables and strings
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader  (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String sumNumbers;
    //String go;
    double num ;
    double total = 0.0;

    // asks user questions and instructions
    System.out.println("Hello, the following program will ask for your input of a number ");
    System.out.println("Each time you input a number a running total will be added to each previous number")  ;
    System.out.println("Once ready input a number to start!");
    // try and catch block      
    try {

      num = 0;

      // while statement if this occurs stop the program, in this case if a negative integer is inputted

      while (num >= 0) {

        // Contious question asked  
        System.out.println("Input another number..."); 
        sumNumbers = myInput.readLine();
        num = Double.parseDouble (sumNumbers);

        // calculates number (Running total)
        total = total + num;
        System.out.println(total);

        // end error trap
      }
    }
    catch  (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Please refrain from entering regular characters!");
      num = 0;

      // re- while statement if this occurs stop the program, in this case if a negative integer is inputted

      while ( num >= 0) {

        // input question after a character is inputted
        System.out.println("Please input a number: ");
        sumNumbers = myInput.readLine();
        num = Double.parseDouble (sumNumbers);

        total = total + num;
        System.out.println(total);

        // ending statement
      }
    }
    System.out.println("You entered a negative number, the program will exit now");
    System.out.println("Good-bye!");

    // Complete class body
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reformulate your second sentence and give us the full stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: seems like you to need refactor your code and introduce a method (that throws exception) to input data from user

Comment: When you are putting the same code in the catch block as the try block, is is a very good sign that something fundamental is wrong with your logic.

Comment: Hard to understand your problem.  Maybe the exception is coming from the code in your catch block.  Note, most of the code in the catch is the same as the try body, maybe refactoring that code into a method would make your code clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something to catch the exception around the Double.parseDouble

for example.

```
 while(num >= 0)
    {
    // input question after a character is inputted
       System.out.println("Please input a number: ");
       sumNumbers = myInput.readLine();
       try{
            num = Double.parseDouble (sumNumbers);
            total = total + num;
            System.out.println(total);
       } catch(Exception e)
       {
            System.out.println("Please enter a proper number");
       }    


            // ending statement
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I am very grateful, but those others who complain about my question not being specific enough. Please note i am new and taking a course, so please don't stress me completely since I am completely new at the subject

Comment: remove the outside try catch block. so that the only try catch is the one inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that as soon as the first exception is thrown, your program becomes caught up inside the while() loop inside of your catch statement.  Thus, if another invalid input is entered, it is dealt with in that second while loop where you have no try-catch statement.  A good fix would be to have your try statement encompass only the line where you say num = Double.parseDouble (sumNumbers);.  When you catch the exception, end it with a continue; statement so that your program loops back the beginning and asks for another input.